# The system cannot find the file specified when running CMD.exe from C#

Tags: c#, cmd

I'm getting the error message when running the following code from a C# console program.

> "The system cannot find the file
>   specified"

Here is the code:

> System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
>   /c");

Strangely when i omit the /c switch the command can run!?!

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem but from command line: U:\>cmd.exe
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
The system cannot find the path specified.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Process.Start` takes a filename as an argument.  Pass the argument as the second parameter:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe", "/c");
```

Answer (score 7):

Well, for one thing, you're hard-coding a path, which is already destined to break on somebody's system (not every Windows install is in `C:\Windows`).

But the problem here is that those backslashes are being used as an escape character.  There are two ways to write a path string like this - either escape the backslashes:

```
Process.Start("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", "/c");
```

Or use the `@` to disable backslash escaping:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe", "/c");
```

You also need to pass `/c` as an argument, not as part of the path - use the second overload of `Process.Start` as shown above.

Answer (score 3):

There is an overload of start to take arguements. Use that one instead.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe",  "/c");
```

Answer (score 3):

I can see three problems with code you posted:

1) You aren't escaping your path string correctly
2) You need to pass the /c argument seperately to the path you want to execute
3) You are assuming every machine this code runs on has a c:\windows installation

I'd propose writing it as follows:

```
string cmdPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory,"cmd.exe");
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(cmdPath, "/c");
```

Answer (score 0):

you need add @ before the path. like this:  @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c"

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the issue is you're attempting to pass an Argument (/c) as a part of the path.

The arguments and the file name are two distinct items in the Process class.

Try

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe",  "/c");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way is to add the program to the solution with ADD EXISTING ITEM and type

```
System::Diagnostics::Process::Start("ccsetup305.exe");
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to answer the question asked.  The OP has to do with command line arguments, which you're not demonstrating at all.